# Productivity stack for new startup

Tags: productivity, google, slack

I am setting up the technical side of a startup, and I need to set up a productivity stack (email, messaging, document sharing, etc). The team is going to be very small for at least a year, under 10 people.

I want to use Slack for messaging and Notion as a team wiki, and then I'd also like to have email coming from our domain name (and in a nice email app).

However, it seems to me the cheapest option to get it all is to use Microsoft Office 365 or Google Workspaces. But I find Office 365 (apart from Teams) to be quite clunky, and Google doesn't seem to have a very good chat app.

Any recommendations? Maybe a combination of Google Workspaces, Slack, and Notion? Or is that overkill?